# r - Klemm and Eguiluz graph model in igraph

Tags: r, graph, social-networking, igraph

I was wondering if igraph has any function to implement the algorithm proposed by Klemm and Eguiluz (2002) that combines all three properties of real world networks (high clustering coefficient, short average path length and scale-free degree distribution).

The original papers can be found [here](https://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.65.036123) and [here](http://journals.aps.org/pre/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevE.65.057102).

Checking the [igraph manual](http://igraph.org/c/doc/igraph-Generators.html#idm470936067488) (Graph Generators part), it seems that the candidates are the functions `igraph_barabasi_aging_game` and `igraph_recent_degree_aging_game`. (described in items 2.18 and 2.19)

Using these 2 functions might help, but I do not know exactly what random graph model they are using as reference, and, therefore I do not know what mathematical properties to expect from the graphs generated by them.

In this link [here](https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/igraph-help/2011-01/msg00102.html), @Gabor Csardi (igraph creator) makes reference to some other paper (2 years older than the two references from Klemm and Eguiluz) to address the "aging" aspect of these 2 functions above, but he apparently does not recall the models being used by these functions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Cheers